# Trigger mouseover event on a marker while dragging another marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am currently working on a leaflet app and came across the problem that the mouseover event for a marker is not correctly fired because, when i am hovering over the marker it just fires when the cursor is slighty out of the dragging object.

[image: hover does not work]

So as you can see the hover effect is not triggered because i have an object dragged over the marker but when i hover with the mouse over it without an object the hover effect is of course correctly triggered.

[image: hover works]

Maybe someone has a idea how to solve it or can point me in the right direction

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn´t not managed to solve my problem with the mouse over function but found another solution. Maybe i can help someone with a similar problem.

My solution was to use the plugin 'leaflet-geometryutil'. This plugin gave me the option to calculate the distance from the current point to the nearest layer.

So i created a layer for every line on the map. When i am dragging a marker now i use the geometryutil plugin to find the nearest line-layer layer and change its appearing.